# How can I load the csv data into r? Especially without a file?

Tags: r

Tried to download the data from website but it gives this result. No download occurred.

```
Country Name,Country Code,Region,Year,Fertility Rate
Aruba,ABW,The Americas,1960,4.82
Afghanistan,AFG,Asia,1960,7.45
Angola,AGO,Africa,1960,7.379
Albania,ALB,Europe,1960,6.186
United Arab Emirates,ARE,Middle East,1960,6.928
Argentina,ARG,The Americas,1960,3.109
Armenia,ARM,Asia,1960,4.55
Antigua and Barbuda,ATG,The Americas,1960,4.425
Australia,AUS,Oceania,1960,3.453
Austria,AUT,Europe,1960,2.69
Azerbaijan,AZE,Asia,1960,5.571
Burundi,BDI,Africa,1960,6.953
Belgium,BEL,Europe,1960,2.54
Benin,BEN,Africa,1960,6.282
Burkina Faso,BFA,Africa,1960,6.291
Bangladesh,BGD,Asia,1960,6.725
Bulgaria,BGR,Europe,1960,2.31
Bahrain,BHR,Middle East,1960,7.09
"Bahamas, The",BHS,The Americas,1960,4.495
Bosnia and Herzegovina,BIH,Europe,1960,3.77
Belarus,BLR,Europe,1960,2.67
Belize,BLZ,The Americas,1960,6.5
Bolivia,BOL,The Americas,1960,6.7
Brazil,BRA,The Americas,1960,6.21
Barbados,BRB,The Americas,1960,4.333
Brunei Darussalam,BRN,Asia,1960,6.487
Bhutan,BTN,Asia,1960,6.67
Botswana,BWA,Africa,1960,6.615
Central African Republic,CAF,Africa,1960,5.84
Canada,CAN,The Americas,1960,3.811
Switzerland,CHE,Europe,1960,2.44
Chile,CHL,The Americas,1960,5.113
China,CHN,Asia,1960,5.758
Cote d'Ivoire,CIV,Africa,1960,7.351
Cameroon,CMR,Africa,1960,5.647
"Congo, Rep.",COG,Africa,1960,5.88
Colombia,COL,The Americas,1960,6.807
Comoros,COM,Africa,1960,6.792
Cabo Verde,CPV,Africa,1960,6.885
Costa Rica,CRI,The Americas,1960,6.451
Cuba,CUB,The Americas,1960,4.182
Cyprus,CYP,Europe,1960,3.5
Czech Republic,CZE,Europe,1960,2.09
Germany,DEU,Europe,1960,2.37
Djibouti,DJI,Africa,1960,6.461
Denmark,DNK,Europe,1960,2.57
Dominican Republic,DOM,The Americas,1960,7.555
Algeria,DZA,Africa,1960,7.524
Ecuador,ECU,The Americas,1960,6.721
"Egypt, Arab Rep.",EGY,Africa,1960,6.63
Eritrea,ERI,Africa,1960,6.899
Spain,ESP,Europe,1960,2.86
Estonia,EST,Europe,1960,1.98
Ethiopia,ETH,Africa,1960,6.88
Finland,FIN,Europe,1960,2.72
Fiji,FJI,Oceania,1960,6.461
France,FRA,Europe,1960,2.85
"Micronesia, Fed. Sts.",FSM,Oceania,1960,6.934
Gabon,GAB,Africa,1960,4.384
United Kingdom,GBR,Europe,1960,2.69
Georgia,GEO,Asia,1960,2.964
Ghana,GHA,Africa,1960,6.749
Guinea,GIN,Africa,1960,6.114
"Gambia, The",GMB,Africa,1960,5.573
Guinea-Bissau,GNB,Africa,1960,5.921
Equatorial Guinea,GNQ,Africa,1960,5.505
Greece,GRC,Europe,1960,2.23
Grenada,GRD,The Americas,1960,6.743
Guatemala,GTM,The Americas,1960,6.534
Guam,GUM,Oceania,1960,6.052
Guyana,GUY,The Americas,1960,5.754
"Hong Kong SAR, China",HKG,Asia,1960,5.162
Honduras,HND,The Americas,1960,7.458
Croatia,HRV,Europe,1960,2.332
Haiti,HTI,The Americas,1960,6.324
Hungary,HUN,Europe,1960,2.02
Indonesia,IDN,Asia,1960,5.666
India,IND,Asia,1960,5.906
Ireland,IRL,Europe,1960,3.78
"Iran, Islamic Rep.",IRN,Middle East,1960,6.927
Iraq,IRQ,Middle East,1960,6.252
Iceland,ISL,Europe,1960,4.29
Italy,ITA,Europe,1960,2.37
Jamaica,JAM,The Americas,1960,5.419
Jordan,JOR,Middle East,1960,7.687
Japan,JPN,Asia,1960,2.001
Kazakhstan,KAZ,Asia,1960,4.563
Kenya,KEN,Africa,1960,7.946
Kyrgyz Republic,KGZ,Asia,1960,5.166
Cambodia,KHM,Asia,1960,6.967
Kiribati,KIR,Oceania,1960,6.788
"Korea, Rep.",KOR,Asia,1960,6.155
Kuwait,KWT,Middle East,1960,7.251
Lao PDR,LAO,Asia,1960,5.961
Lebanon,LBN,Middle East,1960,5.739
Liberia,LBR,Africa,1960,6.406
Libya,LBY,Africa,1960,7.202
St. Lucia,LCA,The Americas,1960,6.967
Sri Lanka,LKA,Asia,1960,5.541
Lesotho,LSO,Africa,1960,5.839
Lithuania,LTU,Europe,1960,2.56
Luxembourg,LUX,Europe,1960,2.29
Latvia,LVA,Europe,1960,1.94
"Macao SAR, China",MAC,Asia,1960,4.945
Morocco,MAR,Africa,1960,7.065
Moldova,MDA,Europe,1960,3.328
Madagascar,MDG,Africa,1960,7.3
Maldives,MDV,Asia,1960,7.021
Mexico,MEX,The Americas,1960,6.768
"Macedonia, FYR",MKD,Europe,1960,3.842
Mali,MLI,Africa,1960,6.967
Malta,MLT,Europe,1960,3.62
Myanmar,MMR,Asia,1960,6.051
Montenegro,MNE,Europe,1960,3.521
Mongolia,MNG,Asia,1960,6.953
Mozambique,MOZ,Africa,1960,6.6
Mauritania,MRT,Africa,1960,6.775
Mauritius,MUS,Africa,1960,6.167
Malawi,MWI,Africa,1960,6.94
Malaysia,MYS,Asia,1960,6.194
Namibia,NAM,Africa,1960,6.15
New Caledonia,NCL,Oceania,1960,6.278
Niger,NER,Africa,1960,7.407
Nigeria,NGA,Africa,1960,6.354
Nicaragua,NIC,The Americas,1960,7.336
Netherlands,NLD,Europe,1960,3.12
Norway,NOR,Europe,1960,2.85
Nepal,NPL,Asia,1960,5.959
New Zealand,NZL,Oceania,1960,4.129
Oman,OMN,Middle East,1960,7.247
Pakistan,PAK,Asia,1960,6.6
Panama,PAN,The Americas,1960,5.87
Peru,PER,The Americas,1960,6.971
Philippines,PHL,Asia,1960,7.148
Papua New Guinea,PNG,Oceania,1960,6.275
Poland,POL,Europe,1960,2.98
Puerto Rico,PRI,The Americas,1960,4.657
Portugal,PRT,Europe,1960,3.16
Paraguay,PRY,The Americas,1960,6.5
French Polynesia,PYF,Oceania,1960,5.658
Qatar,QAT,Middle East,1960,6.971
Romania,ROU,Europe,1960,2.34
Russian Federation,RUS,Europe,1960,2.52
Rwanda,RWA,Africa,1960,8.187
Saudi Arabia,SAU,Middle East,1960,7.216
Sudan,SDN,Africa,1960,6.691
Senegal,SEN,Africa,1960,6.951
Singapore,SGP,Asia,1960,5.454
Solomon Islands,SLB,Oceania,1960,6.388
Sierra Leone,SLE,Africa,1960,5.97
El Salvador,SLV,The Americas,1960,6.674
Somalia,SOM,Africa,1960,7.25
South Sudan,SSD,Africa,1960,6.721
Sao Tome and Principe,STP,Africa,1960,6.242
Suriname,SUR,The Americas,1960,6.608
Slovak Republic,SVK,Europe,1960,3.04
Slovenia,SVN,Europe,1960,2.324
Sweden,SWE,Europe,1960,2.17
Swaziland,SWZ,Africa,1960,6.717
Syrian Arab Republic,SYR,Middle East,1960,7.467
Chad,TCD,Africa,1960,6.25
Togo,TGO,Africa,1960,6.521
Thailand,THA,Asia,1960,6.147
Tajikistan,TJK,Asia,1960,6.235
Turkmenistan,TKM,Asia,1960,6.415
Timor-Leste,TLS,Asia,1960,6.373
Tonga,TON,Oceania,1960,7.363
Trinidad and Tobago,TTO,The Americas,1960,5.264
Tunisia,TUN,Africa,1960,7.043
Turkey,TUR,Europe,1960,6.303
Tanzania,TZA,Africa,1960,6.806
Uganda,UGA,Africa,1960,6.999
Ukraine,UKR,Europe,1960,2.24
Uruguay,URY,The Americas,1960,2.88
United States,USA,The Americas,1960,3.654
Uzbekistan,UZB,Asia,1960,6.707
St. Vincent and the Grenadines,VCT,The Americas,1960,7.224
"Venezuela, RB",VEN,The Americas,1960,6.616
Virgin Islands (U.S.),VIR,The Americas,1960,5.615
Vietnam,VNM,Asia,1960,6.348
Vanuatu,VUT,Oceania,1960,7.197
Samoa,WSM,Oceania,1960,7.651
"Yemen, Rep.",YEM,Middle East,1960,7.38
South Africa,ZAF,Africa,1960,6.173
"Congo, Dem. Rep.",COD,Africa,1960,6.001
Zambia,ZMB,Africa,1960,7.018
Zimbabwe,ZWE,Africa,1960,7.158
Aruba,ABW,The Americas,2013,1.669
Afghanistan,AFG,Asia,2013,5.05
Angola,AGO,Africa,2013,6.165
Albania,ALB,Europe,2013,1.771
United Arab Emirates,ARE,Middle East,2013,1.801
Argentina,ARG,The Americas,2013,2.335
Armenia,ARM,Asia,2013,1.553
Antigua and Barbuda,ATG,The Americas,2013,2.088
Australia,AUS,Oceania,2013,1.921
Austria,AUT,Europe,2013,1.44
Azerbaijan,AZE,Asia,2013,2
Burundi,BDI,Africa,2013,6.035
Belgium,BEL,Europe,2013,1.79
Benin,BEN,Africa,2013,4.846
Burkina Faso,BFA,Africa,2013,5.607
Bangladesh,BGD,Asia,2013,2.209
Bulgaria,BGR,Europe,2013,1.5
Bahrain,BHR,Middle East,2013,2.075
"Bahamas, The",BHS,The Americas,2013,1.883
Bosnia and Herzegovina,BIH,Europe,2013,1.272
Belarus,BLR,Europe,2013,1.62
Belize,BLZ,The Americas,2013,2.611
Bolivia,BOL,The Americas,2013,3.017
Brazil,BRA,The Americas,2013,1.801
Barbados,BRB,The Americas,2013,1.791
Brunei Darussalam,BRN,Asia,2013,1.893
Bhutan,BTN,Asia,2013,2.082
Botswana,BWA,Africa,2013,2.864
Central African Republic,CAF,Africa,2013,4.368
Canada,CAN,The Americas,2013,1.61
Switzerland,CHE,Europe,2013,1.52
Chile,CHL,The Americas,2013,1.774
China,CHN,Asia,2013,1.668
Cote d'Ivoire,CIV,Africa,2013,5.063
Cameroon,CMR,Africa,2013,4.781
"Congo, Rep.",COG,Africa,2013,4.919
Colombia,COL,The Americas,2013,1.922
Comoros,COM,Africa,2013,4.56
Cabo Verde,CPV,Africa,2013,2.339
Costa Rica,CRI,The Americas,2013,1.841
Cuba,CUB,The Americas,2013,1.622
Cyprus,CYP,Europe,2013,1.455
Czech Republic,CZE,Europe,2013,1.45
Germany,DEU,Europe,2013,1.38
Djibouti,DJI,Africa,2013,3.262
Denmark,DNK,Europe,2013,1.73
Dominican Republic,DOM,The Americas,2013,2.51
Algeria,DZA,Africa,2013,2.893
Ecuador,ECU,The Americas,2013,2.571
"Egypt, Arab Rep.",EGY,Africa,2013,3.336
Eritrea,ERI,Africa,2013,4.363
Spain,ESP,Europe,2013,1.32
Estonia,EST,Europe,2013,1.56
Ethiopia,ETH,Africa,2013,4.517
Finland,FIN,Europe,2013,1.8
Fiji,FJI,Oceania,2013,2.589
France,FRA,Europe,2013,2.01
"Micronesia, Fed. Sts.",FSM,Oceania,2013,3.294
Gabon,GAB,Africa,2013,3.963
United Kingdom,GBR,Europe,2013,1.92
Georgia,GEO,Asia,2013,1.817
Ghana,GHA,Africa,2013,4.209
Guinea,GIN,Africa,2013,5.094
"Gambia, The",GMB,Africa,2013,5.751
Guinea-Bissau,GNB,Africa,2013,4.906
Equatorial Guinea,GNQ,Africa,2013,4.924
Greece,GRC,Europe,2013,1.29
Grenada,GRD,The Americas,2013,2.171
Guatemala,GTM,The Americas,2013,3.263
Guam,GUM,Oceania,2013,2.406
Guyana,GUY,The Americas,2013,2.585
"Hong Kong SAR, China",HKG,Asia,2013,1.124
Honduras,HND,The Americas,2013,2.442
Croatia,HRV,Europe,2013,1.51
Haiti,HTI,The Americas,2013,3.098
Hungary,HUN,Europe,2013,1.34
Indonesia,IDN,Asia,2013,2.484
India,IND,Asia,2013,2.465
Ireland,IRL,Europe,2013,2.01
"Iran, Islamic Rep.",IRN,Middle East,2013,1.726
Iraq,IRQ,Middle East,2013,4.026
Iceland,ISL,Europe,2013,2.04
Italy,ITA,Europe,2013,1.43
Jamaica,JAM,The Americas,2013,2.26
Jordan,JOR,Middle East,2013,3.244
Japan,JPN,Asia,2013,1.43
Kazakhstan,KAZ,Asia,2013,2.64
Kenya,KEN,Africa,2013,4.406
Kyrgyz Republic,KGZ,Asia,2013,3.2
Cambodia,KHM,Asia,2013,2.683
Kiribati,KIR,Oceania,2013,3.765
"Korea, Rep.",KOR,Asia,2013,1.187
Kuwait,KWT,Middle East,2013,2.6
Lao PDR,LAO,Asia,2013,3.063
Lebanon,LBN,Middle East,2013,1.495
Liberia,LBR,Africa,2013,4.793
Libya,LBY,Africa,2013,2.507
St. Lucia,LCA,The Americas,2013,1.913
Sri Lanka,LKA,Asia,2013,2.339
Lesotho,LSO,Africa,2013,3.222
Lithuania,LTU,Europe,2013,1.6
Luxembourg,LUX,Europe,2013,1.57
Latvia,LVA,Europe,2013,1.44
"Macao SAR, China",MAC,Asia,2013,1.204
Morocco,MAR,Africa,2013,2.535
Moldova,MDA,Europe,2013,1.456
Madagascar,MDG,Africa,2013,4.468
Maldives,MDV,Asia,2013,2.152
Mexico,MEX,The Americas,2013,2.272
"Macedonia, FYR",MKD,Europe,2013,1.511
Mali,MLI,Africa,2013,6.314
Malta,MLT,Europe,2013,1.43
Myanmar,MMR,Asia,2013,2.239
Montenegro,MNE,Europe,2013,1.666
Mongolia,MNG,Asia,2013,2.657
Mozambique,MOZ,Africa,2013,5.418
Mauritania,MRT,Africa,2013,4.662
Mauritius,MUS,Africa,2013,1.44
Malawi,MWI,Africa,2013,5.22
Malaysia,MYS,Asia,2013,1.956
Namibia,NAM,Africa,2013,3.56
New Caledonia,NCL,Oceania,2013,2.28
Niger,NER,Africa,2013,7.623
Nigeria,NGA,Africa,2013,5.707
Nicaragua,NIC,The Americas,2013,2.3
Netherlands,NLD,Europe,2013,1.72
Norway,NOR,Europe,2013,1.85
Nepal,NPL,Asia,2013,2.292
New Zealand,NZL,Oceania,2013,1.95
Oman,OMN,Middle East,2013,2.823
Pakistan,PAK,Asia,2013,3.682
Panama,PAN,The Americas,2013,2.465
Peru,PER,The Americas,2013,2.48
Philippines,PHL,Asia,2013,3.011
Papua New Guinea,PNG,Oceania,2013,3.812
Poland,POL,Europe,2013,1.3
Puerto Rico,PRI,The Americas,2013,1.636
Portugal,PRT,Europe,2013,1.28
Paraguay,PRY,The Americas,2013,2.581
French Polynesia,PYF,Oceania,2013,2.059
Qatar,QAT,Middle East,2013,2.043
Romania,ROU,Europe,2013,1.53
Russian Federation,RUS,Europe,2013,1.7
Rwanda,RWA,Africa,2013,4.012
Saudi Arabia,SAU,Middle East,2013,2.818
Sudan,SDN,Africa,2013,4.421
Senegal,SEN,Africa,2013,5.134
Singapore,SGP,Asia,2013,1.19
Solomon Islands,SLB,Oceania,2013,4.031
Sierra Leone,SLE,Africa,2013,4.746
El Salvador,SLV,The Americas,2013,1.958
Somalia,SOM,Africa,2013,6.565
South Sudan,SSD,Africa,2013,5.108
Sao Tome and Principe,STP,Africa,2013,4.634
Suriname,SUR,The Americas,2013,2.386
Slovak Republic,SVK,Europe,2013,1.34
Slovenia,SVN,Europe,2013,1.58
Sweden,SWE,Europe,2013,1.91
Swaziland,SWZ,Africa,2013,3.334
Syrian Arab Republic,SYR,Middle East,2013,2.964
Chad,TCD,Africa,2013,6.264
Togo,TGO,Africa,2013,4.655
Thailand,THA,Asia,2013,1.524
Tajikistan,TJK,Asia,2013,3.514
Turkmenistan,TKM,Asia,2013,2.326
Timor-Leste,TLS,Asia,2013,5.2
Tonga,TON,Oceania,2013,3.768
Trinidad and Tobago,TTO,The Americas,2013,1.789
Tunisia,TUN,Africa,2013,2.25
Turkey,TUR,Europe,2013,2.041
Tanzania,TZA,Africa,2013,5.215
Uganda,UGA,Africa,2013,5.869
Ukraine,UKR,Europe,2013,1.506
Uruguay,URY,The Americas,2013,2.033
United States,USA,The Americas,2013,1.8695
Uzbekistan,UZB,Asia,2013,2.2
St. Vincent and the Grenadines,VCT,The Americas,2013,1.997
"Venezuela, RB",VEN,The Americas,2013,2.391
Virgin Islands (U.S.),VIR,The Americas,2013,1.77
Vietnam,VNM,Asia,2013,1.743
Vanuatu,VUT,Oceania,2013,3.383
Samoa,WSM,Oceania,2013,4.147
"Yemen, Rep.",YEM,Middle East,2013,4.284
South Africa,ZAF,Africa,2013,2.387
"Congo, Dem. Rep.",COD,Africa,2013,6.103
Zambia,ZMB,Africa,2013,5.429
Zimbabwe,ZWE,Africa,2013,3.977
```

Comment: Paste this data into a text file. And read it via `read.table()`.

Comment: What do you mean "no download occured"? You obviously have this data, how did you get it? Did you maybe just forgot to assign the data to a variable?
If you are trying to read a .csv, I would recommend the function ```fread()``` from ```library(data.table)```.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to save to a file, select all the text and copy it to your clipboard. For example, I just selected and copied the data in your question. Then in R you can do:

```r
df <- read.csv(file = "clipboard")
```

So now `df` is the following data frame:

```
df
                      Country.Name Country.Code       Region Year Fertility.Rate
1                            Aruba          ABW The Americas 1960          4.820
2                      Afghanistan          AFG         Asia 1960          7.450
3                           Angola          AGO       Africa 1960          7.379
4                          Albania          ALB       Europe 1960          6.186
5             United Arab Emirates          ARE  Middle East 1960          6.928
6                        Argentina          ARG The Americas 1960          3.109
7                          Armenia          ARM         Asia 1960          4.550
8              Antigua and Barbuda          ATG The Americas 1960          4.425
9                        Australia          AUS      Oceania 1960          3.453
10                         Austria          AUT       Europe 1960          2.690
11                      Azerbaijan          AZE         Asia 1960          5.571
12                         Burundi          BDI       Africa 1960          6.953
13                         Belgium          BEL       Europe 1960          2.540
14                           Benin          BEN       Africa 1960          6.282
15                    Burkina Faso          BFA       Africa 1960          6.291
16                      Bangladesh          BGD         Asia 1960          6.725
17                        Bulgaria          BGR       Europe 1960          2.310
18                         Bahrain          BHR  Middle East 1960          7.090
19                    Bahamas, The          BHS The Americas 1960          4.495
20          Bosnia and Herzegovina          BIH       Europe 1960          3.770
21                         Belarus          BLR       Europe 1960          2.670
22                          Belize          BLZ The Americas 1960          6.500
23                         Bolivia          BOL The Americas 1960          6.700
24                          Brazil          BRA The Americas 1960          6.210
25                        Barbados          BRB The Americas 1960          4.333
26               Brunei Darussalam          BRN         Asia 1960          6.487
27                          Bhutan          BTN         Asia 1960          6.670
28                        Botswana          BWA       Africa 1960          6.615
29        Central African Republic          CAF       Africa 1960          5.840
30                          Canada          CAN The Americas 1960          3.811
31                     Switzerland          CHE       Europe 1960          2.440
32                           Chile          CHL The Americas 1960          5.113
33                           China          CHN         Asia 1960          5.758
34                   Cote d'Ivoire          CIV       Africa 1960          7.351
35                        Cameroon          CMR       Africa 1960          5.647
36                     Congo, Rep.          COG       Africa 1960          5.880
37                        Colombia          COL The Americas 1960          6.807
38                         Comoros          COM       Africa 1960          6.792
39                      Cabo Verde          CPV       Africa 1960          6.885
40                      Costa Rica          CRI The Americas 1960          6.451
41                            Cuba          CUB The Americas 1960          4.182
42                          Cyprus          CYP       Europe 1960          3.500
43                  Czech Republic          CZE       Europe 1960          2.090
44                         Germany          DEU       Europe 1960          2.370
45                        Djibouti          DJI       Africa 1960          6.461
46                         Denmark          DNK       Europe 1960          2.570
47              Dominican Republic          DOM The Americas 1960          7.555
48                         Algeria          DZA       Africa 1960          7.524
49                         Ecuador          ECU The Americas 1960          6.721
50                Egypt, Arab Rep.          EGY       Africa 1960          6.630
51                         Eritrea          ERI       Africa 1960          6.899
52                           Spain          ESP       Europe 1960          2.860
53                         Estonia          EST       Europe 1960          1.980
54                        Ethiopia          ETH       Africa 1960          6.880
55                         Finland          FIN       Europe 1960          2.720
56                            Fiji          FJI      Oceania 1960          6.461
57                          France          FRA       Europe 1960          2.850
58           Micronesia, Fed. Sts.          FSM      Oceania 1960          6.934
59                           Gabon          GAB       Africa 1960          4.384
60                  United Kingdom          GBR       Europe 1960          2.690
61                         Georgia          GEO         Asia 1960          2.964
62                           Ghana          GHA       Africa 1960          6.749
63                          Guinea          GIN       Africa 1960          6.114
64                     Gambia, The          GMB       Africa 1960          5.573
65                   Guinea-Bissau          GNB       Africa 1960          5.921
66               Equatorial Guinea          GNQ       Africa 1960          5.505
67                          Greece          GRC       Europe 1960          2.230
68                         Grenada          GRD The Americas 1960          6.743
69                       Guatemala          GTM The Americas 1960          6.534
70                            Guam          GUM      Oceania 1960          6.052
71                          Guyana          GUY The Americas 1960          5.754
72            Hong Kong SAR, China          HKG         Asia 1960          5.162
73                        Honduras          HND The Americas 1960          7.458
74                         Croatia          HRV       Europe 1960          2.332
75                           Haiti          HTI The Americas 1960          6.324
76                         Hungary          HUN       Europe 1960          2.020
77                       Indonesia          IDN         Asia 1960          5.666
78                           India          IND         Asia 1960          5.906
79                         Ireland          IRL       Europe 1960          3.780
80              Iran, Islamic Rep.          IRN  Middle East 1960          6.927
81                            Iraq          IRQ  Middle East 1960          6.252
82                         Iceland          ISL       Europe 1960          4.290
83                           Italy          ITA       Europe 1960          2.370
84                         Jamaica          JAM The Americas 1960          5.419
85                          Jordan          JOR  Middle East 1960          7.687
86                           Japan          JPN         Asia 1960          2.001
87                      Kazakhstan          KAZ         Asia 1960          4.563
88                           Kenya          KEN       Africa 1960          7.946
89                 Kyrgyz Republic          KGZ         Asia 1960          5.166
90                        Cambodia          KHM         Asia 1960          6.967
91                        Kiribati          KIR      Oceania 1960          6.788
92                     Korea, Rep.          KOR         Asia 1960          6.155
93                          Kuwait          KWT  Middle East 1960          7.251
94                         Lao PDR          LAO         Asia 1960          5.961
95                         Lebanon          LBN  Middle East 1960          5.739
96                         Liberia          LBR       Africa 1960          6.406
97                           Libya          LBY       Africa 1960          7.202
98                       St. Lucia          LCA The Americas 1960          6.967
99                       Sri Lanka          LKA         Asia 1960          5.541
100                        Lesotho          LSO       Africa 1960          5.839
101                      Lithuania          LTU       Europe 1960          2.560
102                     Luxembourg          LUX       Europe 1960          2.290
103                         Latvia          LVA       Europe 1960          1.940
104               Macao SAR, China          MAC         Asia 1960          4.945
105                        Morocco          MAR       Africa 1960          7.065
106                        Moldova          MDA       Europe 1960          3.328
107                     Madagascar          MDG       Africa 1960          7.300
108                       Maldives          MDV         Asia 1960          7.021
109                         Mexico          MEX The Americas 1960          6.768
110                 Macedonia, FYR          MKD       Europe 1960          3.842
111                           Mali          MLI       Africa 1960          6.967
112                          Malta          MLT       Europe 1960          3.620
113                        Myanmar          MMR         Asia 1960          6.051
114                     Montenegro          MNE       Europe 1960          3.521
115                       Mongolia          MNG         Asia 1960          6.953
116                     Mozambique          MOZ       Africa 1960          6.600
117                     Mauritania          MRT       Africa 1960          6.775
118                      Mauritius          MUS       Africa 1960          6.167
119                         Malawi          MWI       Africa 1960          6.940
120                       Malaysia          MYS         Asia 1960          6.194
121                        Namibia          NAM       Africa 1960          6.150
122                  New Caledonia          NCL      Oceania 1960          6.278
123                          Niger          NER       Africa 1960          7.407
124                        Nigeria          NGA       Africa 1960          6.354
125                      Nicaragua          NIC The Americas 1960          7.336
126                    Netherlands          NLD       Europe 1960          3.120
127                         Norway          NOR       Europe 1960          2.850
128                          Nepal          NPL         Asia 1960          5.959
129                    New Zealand          NZL      Oceania 1960          4.129
130                           Oman          OMN  Middle East 1960          7.247
131                       Pakistan          PAK         Asia 1960          6.600
132                         Panama          PAN The Americas 1960          5.870
133                           Peru          PER The Americas 1960          6.971
134                    Philippines          PHL         Asia 1960          7.148
135               Papua New Guinea          PNG      Oceania 1960          6.275
136                         Poland          POL       Europe 1960          2.980
137                    Puerto Rico          PRI The Americas 1960          4.657
138                       Portugal          PRT       Europe 1960          3.160
139                       Paraguay          PRY The Americas 1960          6.500
140               French Polynesia          PYF      Oceania 1960          5.658
141                          Qatar          QAT  Middle East 1960          6.971
142                        Romania          ROU       Europe 1960          2.340
143             Russian Federation          RUS       Europe 1960          2.520
144                         Rwanda          RWA       Africa 1960          8.187
145                   Saudi Arabia          SAU  Middle East 1960          7.216
146                          Sudan          SDN       Africa 1960          6.691
147                        Senegal          SEN       Africa 1960          6.951
148                      Singapore          SGP         Asia 1960          5.454
149                Solomon Islands          SLB      Oceania 1960          6.388
150                   Sierra Leone          SLE       Africa 1960          5.970
151                    El Salvador          SLV The Americas 1960          6.674
152                        Somalia          SOM       Africa 1960          7.250
153                    South Sudan          SSD       Africa 1960          6.721
154          Sao Tome and Principe          STP       Africa 1960          6.242
155                       Suriname          SUR The Americas 1960          6.608
156                Slovak Republic          SVK       Europe 1960          3.040
157                       Slovenia          SVN       Europe 1960          2.324
158                         Sweden          SWE       Europe 1960          2.170
159                      Swaziland          SWZ       Africa 1960          6.717
160           Syrian Arab Republic          SYR  Middle East 1960          7.467
161                           Chad          TCD       Africa 1960          6.250
162                           Togo          TGO       Africa 1960          6.521
163                       Thailand          THA         Asia 1960          6.147
164                     Tajikistan          TJK         Asia 1960          6.235
165                   Turkmenistan          TKM         Asia 1960          6.415
166                    Timor-Leste          TLS         Asia 1960          6.373
167                          Tonga          TON      Oceania 1960          7.363
168            Trinidad and Tobago          TTO The Americas 1960          5.264
169                        Tunisia          TUN       Africa 1960          7.043
170                         Turkey          TUR       Europe 1960          6.303
171                       Tanzania          TZA       Africa 1960          6.806
172                         Uganda          UGA       Africa 1960          6.999
173                        Ukraine          UKR       Europe 1960          2.240
174                        Uruguay          URY The Americas 1960          2.880
175                  United States          USA The Americas 1960          3.654
176                     Uzbekistan          UZB         Asia 1960          6.707
177 St. Vincent and the Grenadines          VCT The Americas 1960          7.224
178                  Venezuela, RB          VEN The Americas 1960          6.616
179          Virgin Islands (U.S.)          VIR The Americas 1960          5.615
180                        Vietnam          VNM         Asia 1960          6.348
181                        Vanuatu          VUT      Oceania 1960          7.197
182                          Samoa          WSM      Oceania 1960          7.651
183                    Yemen, Rep.          YEM  Middle East 1960          7.380
184                   South Africa          ZAF       Africa 1960          6.173
185               Congo, Dem. Rep.          COD       Africa 1960          6.001
186                         Zambia          ZMB       Africa 1960          7.018
187                       Zimbabwe          ZWE       Africa 1960          7.158
188                          Aruba          ABW The Americas 2013          1.669
189                    Afghanistan          AFG         Asia 2013          5.050
190                         Angola          AGO       Africa 2013          6.165
191                        Albania          ALB       Europe 2013          1.771
192           United Arab Emirates          ARE  Middle East 2013          1.801
193                      Argentina          ARG The Americas 2013          2.335
194                        Armenia          ARM         Asia 2013          1.553
195            Antigua and Barbuda          ATG The Americas 2013          2.088
196                      Australia          AUS      Oceania 2013          1.921
197                        Austria          AUT       Europe 2013          1.440
198                     Azerbaijan          AZE         Asia 2013          2.000
199                        Burundi          BDI       Africa 2013          6.035
200                        Belgium          BEL       Europe 2013          1.790
```

Comment: Should I copy the URL of the data while using this function

Comment: If you have the url of the data (say the url was "http:// www.data.com/data.csv") you could just do `read.csv("http://www.data.com/data.csv")`

Comment: Thanks,I'll try with your new tip

Answer (score 2):

We can use `soread` from `overflow` package after selecting and copying the file

```
library(overflow)
df1 <- soread(sep=",")
head(df1)
#          Country.Name Country.Code       Region Year Fertility.Rate
#1                Aruba          ABW The Americas 1960          4.820
#2          Afghanistan          AFG         Asia 1960          7.450
#3               Angola          AGO       Africa 1960          7.379
#4              Albania          ALB       Europe 1960          6.186
#5 United Arab Emirates          ARE  Middle East 1960          6.928
#6            Argentina          ARG The Americas 1960          3.109
```

Comment: I didn't know about this package akrun. Looks like it could be very helpful. Thank you!